# Both IPN and LCN for Avangate

Tags: avangate

We are going to sell a service through Avangate. The payment is recurring, so I considered to use only LCN (without IPN) for verifying purchases.

However:

1. I am not sure if the first recurring payment is reported through LCN (not through IPN only).
2. Our price is generated on-the-fly. So I need to check the price against cheating by customers. However there is no price in LCN, only in IPN.
3. This means that I should use both LCN and IPN, right? But can I be sure that the first LCN always goes after my response to the IPN?